# Oracle xmltype query and update

Tags: oracle, xmltype

My xmltype field value will be as below:

```
<c1>100</c1>
<c1 m=“2”>50</c1>
<c1 m=“3”>10</c1>
<c1 m=“4”>60</c1>
```

My query is to display the nodes greater than 50 and update the value as 100.

Answer (score 1):

```sql
UPDATE table_name
SET    column_name = UPDATEXML( column_name, '/c1/text()', 100 )
WHERE  EXTRACTVALUE( column_name, '/c1' ) > 50
```

For your test data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( column_name ) AS
SELECT XMLTYPE( '<c1>100</c1>' ) FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT XMLTYPE( '<c1 m="2">50</c1>' ) FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT XMLTYPE( '<c1 m="3">10</c1>' ) FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT XMLTYPE( '<c1 m="4">60</c1>' ) FROM DUAL
```

Then:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name;
```

Outputs:

> ```
> | COLUMN_NAME            |
> | :--------------------- |
> | <c1>100</c1><br>       |
> | <c1 m="2">50</c1><br>  |
> | <c1 m="3">10</c1><br>  |
> | <c1 m="4">100</c1><br> |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=a4efd5017abffa23e2812da663ad601b)*

---

If you have multiple `c1` elements wrapped in root element then you can use an `XMLQUERY` statement:

```sql
UPDATE table_name
SET    column_name = XMLQuery(
         'copy $i := $c modify
         (for $j in $i/row/c1 where $j > 50
           return replace value of node $j with 100)
         return $i'
         PASSING column_name AS "c"
         RETURNING CONTENT
       )
WHERE  XMLEXISTS( '/row[c1 > 50]' PASSING column_name )
```

So, for your test data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( column_name ) AS
SELECT XMLTYPE( '<row><c1>100</c1><c1 m="2">50</c1><c1 m="3">10</c1><c1 m="4">60</c1></row>' ) FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT XMLTYPE( '<row><c1>10</c1></row>' ) FROM DUAL
```

This outputs:

> ```
> | COLUMN_NAME                                                                                                 |
> | :---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
> | <row><br>  <c1>100</c1><br>  <c1 m="2">50</c1><br>  <c1 m="3">10</c1><br>  <c1 m="4">100</c1><br></row><br> |
> | <row><br>  <c1>10</c1><br></row><br>                                                                        |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=01bb3be08515340615369c63c1a13d6a)*

Comment: Thanks for your response, the column is an xmltype and the tags shown are XML values of one row. 

Below will be my overall xmltype of record

<row Id =“1”> <c1>100</c1>
<c1 m=“2”>50</c1>
<c1 m=“3”>10</c1>
<c1 m=“4”>60</c1>
<\row>